# innerhtml don't work from a javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
document.getElementById('sameid').innerHTML=same-value;
```

`same-value`- could be java script var,xml file, text file,php or just test as "hello" and it don't work from a `js` file.

from the `html/xhtml` file it's working fine the same command, why?

the html saved as `xhtml` and the page is write well and the `js` pass the test of java script google so what is the problem?

the `js` file loaded to the `html/xhtml` file and working fine till this command is been used in the `js` file.

i'm working firefox and chrome and the result is the same in both browsers.

Comment: What error are you getting in your javascript?

Comment: Where did you place this code in your html file? And what does your javascript file look like now?

Comment: Do you call this in the body or the head, and have you wrapped the call in an `onload` function?

Answer (score 0):

Expecting same-value to be a "string" (the quotes are needed) or a declared variable for some text.

Also double check that document.getElementById('sameid') is not null.

Comment: And that you include the script after the required element has been created, usually by putting it at the end of the body.

Answer (score 0):

i found a way to make that work.

```
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("some_tag");
var strings= new String;
var i=0;//or other number i want to print from the xml array.
strings="";
strings=strings+(x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
document.getElementById("categories").innerHTML=strings;
```

for a reason i don't know:

```
document.getElementById('sameid').innerHTML=x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

don't work and i have to use $strings that geting the value first and then the value pass into the:

```
document.getElementById('sameid').innerHTML
```